# Grafana is Auto-Manipulating Timezone from MySQL Datasource and it's unclear how to correct

Tags: grafana

So I've got a MySQL datasource with a unix timestamp. When I query data from the table, Grafana is auto-adjusting the timestamp for me. I understand I can set the timezone when configuring the data source, but that is having mixed results. Depending on *how* I select/transform the column in the query, Grafana manipulates the time.

Here's an example where Grafana gives me back different times querying the same data.

`last_updated_ts` is timezone adjusted when I provide a [FORMAT], but when I don't there's no timezone adjustment.

[screenshot of SQL statement in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5mZo.png)

Is there any logic to this? What's the best strategy to just get back my timestamp without manipulating the timezone? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Depending on how I select/transform the column in the query, Grafana manipulates the time

This is not exactly Grafana's fault.

You see, when you query `FROM_UNIXTIME(my_timestamp)` MySQL returns `DATETIME`, but when you query `FROM_UNIXTIME(my_timestamp, '%y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')` it returns `VARCHAR`.

Grafana automatically adjusts every datetime field (or what assumed to be datetime field, for example column with name `time`) to local timezone.

I don't think you should do something about it. Configure timezone shift between Grafana's server and MySQL server (if any), and stop querying database dates as strings, and you should be fine.